# Sending epsilon to zero (in the proof of the weak maximum principle)

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

In the proof of the weak maximum principle of the diffusion equation, I came across the part that [says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0NKN.png):

> Let $\epsilon$ be a positive constant and let $v(x, t)=u(x, t)+\epsilon x^{2} .$ Our goal is to show that $v(x, t) \leq M+\epsilon l^{2}$ throughout $R .$ Once this is accomplished, we'll have $u(x, t) \leq M+\epsilon\left(l^{2}-x^{2}\right) .$ This conclusion is true for any $\epsilon>0$ Therefore, $u(x, t) \leq M$ throughout $R,$ which is what we are trying to prove.

Why does showing $u(x,t)\leq M + \epsilon \cdot l^2 $ finish our proof that $u(x,t)\leq M $?
Surely, $\epsilon>0$ and $l^2-x^2 >0$, but why would $u(x,t)\leq M $ hold?

Intuitively, I think it's sending epsilon to zero, but I don't know the detailed process of it.

Comment: This is an elementary exercise that if $a \le b + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$, then $a\le b$. The proof is by contradiction.

Comment: @ArcticChar
this is what I have: Suppose $a \leq b + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$ and $ b<a$. Then, for all $\epsilon >0$, $ b < a \leq b + \epsilon$ so $b < b + \epsilon$.... Where does the contradiction come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a \leq b + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. Equivalently, $a < b + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. If $a>b$, then $a-b >0$, so $a < b + (a - b) = a$, contradiction. Hence, $a \leq b$.

Comment: Thank you! One question: Why does "a≦b+ε for all ε>0" imply "a<b+ε for all ε>0" ? (From the first sentence to the second sentence) What about the case when a=b+ε? What am I getting wrong about the supposition?

Comment: @Stone If $\epsilon > 0$, then $\frac{\epsilon}{2}>0$, so $a \leq b + \frac{\epsilon}{2} < b + \epsilon$.